# how to print out the next year in a while loop or if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, leap-year

I am currently doing a online practise course by myself. This is the code that i have so far. the code only prints out correctly one of the conditions. The if leap condition prints out both print statements. How do i get the if leap to only print out one statement and to ignore what comes after it.

```py
inp_year = int(input("Give year:"))
  
year = inp_year

leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

if leap:
    print("The next leap year from",year,"is",year + 4)
    
while not leap:
    year += 1
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

print("The next leap year from",inp_year,"is",year)
```

Comment: Please fix code indentation to match your running code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the else statement like this:

```py
if leap:
    # Code to run when leap is True
    print("The next leap year from",year,"is",year + 4)

else:
    # Your other code to run when leap is False
    while not leap:
        year += 1

        leap = year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 ==0

    print("The next leap year from",inp_year,"is",year)
```

The `if` statement runs code indented inside it if the condition is True. Similarly, you can have `elif` statements after the `if` to check for other conditions. Finally, the `else` statement runs code inside it if none of the previous `if` and `elif` conditions are True.